# How to align contents by using flexbox? align-contnent and justify-contnent didn't worrk

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

First of all, thank you for helping me out in advance. I tried to align three contents giving even space in each row.
Like this image.
[image]

So, I tried to use flexbox to do this! display with flex, flex-direction: column;, and using align-items or justify-contents. However, it didn't work what I expaected. I guess the contents would be displaied clearly like the above picture. However, it shows like this picture.
[image]

Could you help me with this problem? I will leave my code below!

```
.contentsWrapper {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
    // background-color: blue;
    padding: 5px;
    .contentsSide {
      width: 280px;
      padding-left: 48px;
      padding-right: 48px;
      .HorizontalLine {
        width: 160px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      }
      .colors {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        span {
          margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
        .colorLists {
          margin-left: 10px;
          float: left;
          .colorLayout {
            float: left;
            // flex-wrap: wrap;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            // justify-content: space-between;
            // align-content: space-around;
            position: relative;
            // display: grid;
            // grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 20%);
            margin-right: 15px;
            margin-left: 3px;
            label {
              background-color: beige;
              border: 1px solid #ccc;
              border-radius: 50%;
              cursor: pointer;
              height: 28px;
              left: 0;
              position: absolute;
              top: 40;
              width: 28px;
              &:after {
                border: 2px solid #fff;
                border-top: none;
                border-right: none;
                content: '';
                height: 6px;
                left: 7px;
                opacity: 0;
                position: absolute;
                top: 8px;
                transform: rotate(-45deg);
                width: 12px;
              }
            }
            input[type='checkbox'] {
              visibility: hidden;
            }
            input[type='checkbox']:checked {
              & + label {
                background-color: beige;
                border-color: beige;
                &:after {
                  opacity: 1;
                }
              }
            }

            .productColor {
              margin-top: 15px;
              font-size: 13px;
              width: 61.25;
              height: 25px;
            }
          }
        }
      }
      .sizes {
        .HorizontalLine {
        }
        .span {
        }
        .sizeLists {
          margin-top: 20px;
          margin-bottom: 20px;
          button {
            margin: 5px;
          }
        }
```

This is JS file

```
<ul className="colorLists">
                  {COLOR_LISTS.map(color => {
                    return (
                      <li className="colorLayout" title="베이지">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"></input>
                        <label
                          for="checkbox"
                          style={{ backgroundColor: color.colorProps }}
                        ></label>
                        <span className="productColor">{color.color_name}</span>
                      </li>
                    );
                  })}
                </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cool, so you're pretty close by the look of it, you just need to take advantage of flexbox wrapping and set a width for the elements on each row.

Try something like this:

```
.colorLists {
  margin-left: 10px;
  display: flex; // the color list should be display flex
  flex-wrap: wrap; // allow elements to wrap on the the next row
  .colorLayout {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 33%; // this will allow the color to span 1 third
    flex-shrink: 0; // this fill force the row to wrap every third element
    align-items: center; // this will help center the content
    justify-content: center; // this will also help center the content
    label {
      // include your label styles
    }
    input[type='checkbox'] {
      visibility: hidden;
    }
    input[type='checkbox']:checked {
      & + label {
        background-color: beige;
        border-color: beige;
        &:after {
          opacity: 1;
        }
      }
    }

    .productColor {
      margin-top: 15px;
      font-size: 13px;
      width: 61.25;
      height: 25px;
    }
  }
}
```

I didn't include the styles that were unnecessary to your question, but the important thing is make the parent container `display: flex` and `flex-wrap: wrap` and the making the children divs `width: 33%` and you might need `flex-shrink: 0`. From there you should be able to play around and get everything else working, but essentially those few styles on the parent div and then the children divs should do what you want.

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for your detailed explanation and code with comments. It is very easy to understand what you mean! I get some new information; flex-shrink and give flex property & wrap to the top part! Thank you for your help!